# Toggle button when click out of button

Tags: angularjs

I have two states for a button, `"State1"` and `"State2"`.

It defaults to `"State2"`. When I click the button, it toggles to `"State1"`.
When I click anywhere outside the button, I need it to change from `"State1"` back to `"State2"`.  This is my code:

```
<div ng-click="Ctrl.Check = !Ctrl.Check">
            <a ng-class="{'btn-danger': !Ctrl.Check, 'btn-default': Ctrl.Check }" >
                {{ Ctrl.Check ? 'State1' : 'State2' }}
            </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `class="btn"` to the A element

Comment: When you say "click out of button" do you mean when the button loses focus (on-blur)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu
I mean not click button to trigger toggle

Comment: Clicking anywhere outside of the button?

Comment: Yes, I mean this
@ryanyuyu

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just checking whether the element has focus.  This is much easier than putting down a bunch of `ng-click` handlers all over your form just to toggle one input.

Use [`ng-focus`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) and the corresponding `ng-blur`.  If you use HTML elements that can have focus (like a `<button>`), you can use code like

```
<button type="button" class="btn" 
    ng-class="{'btn-danger': !Ctrl.Check, 'btn-default': Ctrl.Check }" 
    ng-focus="Ctrl.Check = true"
    ng-blur="Ctrl.Check = false">
    {{ Ctrl.Check ? 'State1' : 'State2' }}
</button>
```

[Demo on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/O5p7A3VK6LzRo5a09hvw?p=preview)

Comment: How can you make it toggle when you click the button at the same time?

Comment: Wait.  Toggle on click and on blur?  That makes little sense.  But you could just add `ng-click="Ctrl.Check = !Ctrl.Check"` or something like that.